# Can someone help me with this IF statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Ok - so, I made an onscreen keyboard where the user turns the caps lock on and the box changes from black to white, then changes back when it's clicked again.

```
private void checkBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        checkBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
        checkBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = true;
        checkBox1.BackColor = Color.Black;
        checkBox1.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
    }
```

This is how I think the above code works:

1. Caps lock starts off (checked = false)
2. User clicks caps lock (which changes checked to true)
3. The code should change the box to white
4. The box changes back to black when user clicks the button again (because checked = false)

I'm sure I'm misunderstanding this somewhere, but I can't nail it.

The point of this is that currently it isn't changing colour at all - somehow I forgot to add that.

Comment: Have you used a debugger (or prints) to check that your event handler is called?

Comment: Just for the future - `capslock` is not related to checkboxes. `Capslock` is a key on the keyboard.

Comment: Yeah sorry I will write my questions better in the future. Thanks Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`CheckBox.CheckedChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event rather than the [`Control.Click`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event.

At that point, the following should work:

```
checkBox1.BackColor = checkBox1.Checked ? Color.White : Color.Black;
checkBox1.ForeColor = checkBox1.Checked ? Color.Black : Color.White;
```

You don't need to handle the `Click` event and then set the `Checked` property manually. Handling `CheckChanged` should do it for you.

Comment: This, tied with a small fix on my half in the else statement fixed this. Thanks a lot! Though I've never seen it written like 
checkBox1.Checked ? Color.White : Color.Black;
before. I shall do more studying! Thanks again mate.

Comment: That is ternary operator used in place of if else. 
condition ? first : second;
if condition is true, first expression is evaluated and becomes the result; if false, the second expression is evaluated and becomes the result.

Comment: @Adam199990 To add on to learningNew, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) is a reference on the ternary operator that I used (the conditional operator).

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I'm still learning so always thankful for a point in the right direction to help me out. Thanks a lot. I like this ternary operator!